# Basic Highcharts Multiple Series Chart Using JSON

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to create a basic line chart that contains three series of data in a json file. The json file is name `json.json` for this example. I have validated the JSON format using [JSON Formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

**JSON Format Example**

```
{
"Series1 (Units1)": [100 ,200 ,300],
"Series2 (Units2)": [10, 20, 30],
"Series3 (Units3)": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

**Current Code Being Used** from a another example I found

```
$(function () {

    $.getJSON('data/json.json', function (data) {
        console.log(data)
        var processedData = [];
        Highcharts.each(data, function (d) {
            processedData.push(d.Series);
        });

        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Series'
            },

            series: [{
                data: processedData
            }]

        });
    });

});
```

I have mocked up an example of the chart I am trying to achieve using [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kinser86/ez1ufL10/).

I also tried following along with this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83gsyaLu/) from another post but the JSON data will not load when I try to modify it.

I have checked that the data is being fetched by adding the line `console.log(data)`

How can I get the data to load into the chart using this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert you JSON from `key: value` to proper series format, which in your case is something similar to:

```
[{ 
    name: 'my series', 
    data: [1,2,3] 
}, ...];
```

Currently your `processedData` formatting is not correct, so the end result put into Highcharts `series` is invalid.

In, short, your events GET, process and display could look something like this ([CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wjrYqp)):

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/yu6gq', function (data) {
        var processedData = [];

        for(var entry in data) {
            processedData.push({
              name: entry,
              data: data[entry]
            });
        }

        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            series: processedData
        });
    });
});
```

Its still just the task of creating the proper `processedData` array, containing `Series` objects with the correct format. In this example each `Series` is given the `name` and `data` attributes, filled in with values from your JSON.

Comment: This was the answer. I needed to parse the data regarding the name and the data, iterating through the series format mentioned above. Thank you so much. I know this was a basic example but it is exactly what I needed and wanted.